# Combinations and Statistics Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

A bin with 100 parts contains 8 that are defective. A sample of 10 parts are obtained. How many samples contain exactly 1 defective part?

My answer was 10 as each defective part is mathematically indistinguishable from each other and the same for the non defective parts. Therefor, the defective part can occur in 10 different places in the sample leading to 10 different possible samples. I feel like the information before that was misleading.

Edit: I want to clarify that I think the question was poorly worded and ambiguous which is why I am looking for clarification and maybe my interpretation was flawed.

Comment: You take one sample and you are asked for the number of samples? This looks like a contradiction to me.

Comment: Maybe the question is what is the probability that a sample contains exactly 1 defective part.

Comment: This was a quiz question that confused me and I interpreted it to mean the possible number of ordered sequences (which the sample is) that contain exactly one defective part

Comment: It was not the probability, it was number of samples

Comment: The confusion was whether to treat each defective/ non-defective parts as indistinguishable from each other

Comment: The problem is very poorly phrased.  Maybe (just maybe) they are asking you to divide the bin into ten samples of ten parts each and are asking for the expected number of samples with exactly one defective part.  At least that is a fair question.  But it is so vague that any interpretation is only going to be a guess.

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is flawed because it doesn't take into account how many defective pieces there are. Also, you are not actually told that the defective pieces are indistinguishable. You could have a bin of 100 different parts, 8 of which are defective.

To count the number of 10-piece samples that contain exactly 1 defective piece, you need to count how many ways there are to choose 1 defective piece, and how many ways there are to choose 9 non-defective pieces, and multiply those numbers together. You do not care what order these pieces are in, by the way. The samples don't have any ordering to them.

Comment: Why would I have reason to believe they are distinguishable? The default in set theory is that there is no distinguishing between the same type of element.

Comment: If I have 3 pairs of jeans and 2 pairs of khakis, how many ways can I choose a pair of blue jeans? Just one? No, there are 3 I can choose from.

Comment: [look at this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics))"In mathematics, an element, or member, of a set is any one of the distinct objects that make up that set".The example you gave is interesting, but with physical objects you can distinguish between them as you have more information. If the only information I was given was defective and non defective then it is a totally valid interpretation to say the sample space consists of two outcomes. I concede there is no reason to order the sample though, but it would have left the question with basically nothing to answer.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of what elements of sets are. I am also well versed in combinatorics and counting problems, and I am telling you that in problems like this one, two samples will *not* be considered the same just because they have the same *number* of defective/non-defective pieces.

Comment: Have a look at binomial coefficients: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Definition_and_interpretations. $\binom{n}{k}$ counts the number of ways $k$ elements can be chosen from an $n$ element set. If you insist on treating your defective/non-defective pieces as the same element, then your set of objects to choose from only has size 2! How can you choose 10 objects from a set of size 2?

Comment: But what reason was I given to believe that they are different? Without any indication I defaulted to members of the same type being indistinguishable.

Comment: Because if it was an ordered sequence duplicates are allowed as my interpretation

Comment: Can we both agree the question could have used a little more clarification on the nature of what "part" or "sample" meant? I feel like the question is ambiguous otherwise

Comment: If this is the first time you are seeing a problem like this, then I agree it should be clarified what is meant, i.e., what samples are to be considered different. My interpretation is the way these questions are typically meant to be interpreted.

Comment: It was my first time. This was the first quiz of the semester and there wasn't a problem like this in the problem handout or homework. I even checked my textbook for definitions and nothing was there so I am quite frustrated.